# how to do a weighted division on a set of nodes based on a their number

Tags: java, algorithm, cluster-computing, partitioning

I have a number of nodes for example 100 nodes, I want to have 10 parent nodes and 9 nodes per each node.

this code works fine at the beginning, but it scales when we get more nodes than 44

```
    for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println("i : "+i);
        int x = new Testing().getSubMastersNumber(i);
        System.out.println("sub-Masters number : "+x);
        int result = i/x-1;
        System.out.println(" remaining nodes:  "+ i % x +"\t number of node by SubMaster : "+result);
        System.out.println("");
    }

public int getSubMastersNumber(int num) {
    return (num>1)? 1+getSubMastersNumber(num/2):0;
}
```

Comment: Define `it scales` please

Comment: it becomes scalable 

i : 88
sub-Masters number : 6
 remaining nodes:  4  number of node by SM : 13

13 nodes for 6 parent nodes

Comment: It is integer division, discarding the remainder, so `(i + x - 1)/x` maybe. But I do not (want to) understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way how to get the number of parent nodes

if the number has a decimal part equals to 0 then we do not add 1 parent
example : sqrt(9) = 3.0

parents = 3  nodes per parent = 2 and the remaining nodes = 0

```
public static int getSM(int num) {
        return ((Math.sqrt(num)-(double)((int) (Math.sqrt(num))))==0) ? (int)Math.sqrt(num) : (int)Math.sqrt(num)+1;    
    }
```

the number of nodes by parent node

```
public static int nodePerSM(int num) {
        return (int) ((num - getSM(num))/getSM(num));
    }
```

the problem is that there is always some remaining nodes

```
public static int remainingNodes(int num) {
        return (num - getSM(num))-(nodePerSM(num)*getSM(num));
    }
```

we add 1 node to each parent
using a loop

example : number of nodes = 14

sqrt(14) = 3.74.....
decimalPart(sqrt(14))= 0.74...

in this case the number of parents is 3+1 = 4

nodes per parent is 14 - 4 = 10 
10/4 = 2

remaining nodes number is (14-4)-(2*4) = 2

2 parents will have 3 child nodes
the others will have 2